# Need help understanding LVITEM state and stateMask

Tags: winapi, common-controls

I'm confused. The [LVITEM structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb774760) states:

> **state**
>
> Type: **UINT**
>
> Indicates the item's state, state image, and overlay image. The **stateMask** member indicates the valid bits of this member.
>
> Bits 0 through 7 of this member contain the item state flags. This can be one or more of the item state values.

So my question is, what are bits 0 through 7 for?  They appear not to indicate what is used by the other bits, otherwise the **stateMask** wouldn't be needed.

Comment: @KenWhite, Yes, I read that. You state _`state` is used to set multiple values at once._, but that is what `stateMask` is already doing, as stated by your quote of the documentation.

Comment: *Bits 0 through 7 of this member contain the [item state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774733) flags. This can be one or more of the item state values.*

Comment: @RbMm, yes, I read that.  So, what is the expected response when setting `state` bits 0-7 to `LVIS_OVERLAYMASK` or `LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK`?  Garbage?

Comment: @Adrian, take a look at LVIS_OVERLAYMASK/LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK values, it's 0x0f00/0xf000. Obviously you can't set first byte to this value. stateMask and state use the same LVIS_* flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN tells you exactly what the bits in `state` are:

> Bits 0 through 7 of this member contain the item state flags. This can be one or more of the [item state values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774733).
>
> Bits 8 through 11 of this member specify the one-based overlay image index. ... To isolate these bits, use the LVIS_OVERLAYMASK mask.
>
> Bits 12 through 15 of this member specify the state image index. To isolate these bits, use the LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK mask.

It does not make sense to set the bottom bits to `LVIS_*MASK`, only the other `LVIS_*` states. `stateMask` specifies which bits in `state` are required/valid when you query or set the state.

The bit layout of `state` and `stateMask` is the same and if someone hands you a `LVITEM` you would calculate the valid bits as `valid = lvi.state & lvi.stateMask`. If the state bits you care about are not set in `stateMask` you would have to query the listview for those bits.

In the source code for the listview the query code might look something like this:

```
void ListView::GetItemState(LVITEM&lvi, int idx)
{
  lvi.state = 0;
  if ((lvi.stateMask & LVIS_CUT) && isItemInCutState(idx, lvi)) lvi.state |= LVIS_CUT;
  if ((lvi.stateMask & LVIS_...) && ...
}
```

Comment: So, the bits in `state` should only accept values that don't match `LVIS_*MASK`, and the `stateMask` will indicate what bits will be updated in `state`?  You state that *"If the bits you care about are not set in stateMask you would have to query the listview for those bits.*" What other way would I query the listview for those bits?  Or would I use the same call with different `stateMask`?

Comment: The bits you want to query must be set in stateMask. `lvi.stateMask = LVIS_CUT; ListView_...(); isCut = lvi.state & LVIS_CUT;`

Answer (score 0):

There are two bits of information you want to communicate: The final value of each flag, and the set of flags you want to adjust. Those are represented by the `state` and `stateMask` members, respectively.

The operation performed is:

```cpp
auto flags = prev_flags & ~( state | stateMask ); // reset flags
     flags = flags      |  ( state & stateMask ); // set flags
```

An example: Assuming `prev_flags` is `101` and you wish to reset flag 0, set flag 1, and keep flag 2 unchanged, you'd pass `010` as the `state` and `011` as the `stateMask`. Note, that the `stateMask` denotes `0` for flag 2, to retain its current value.

`state & stateMask` evaluates to `010`.

`~( state | stateMask )` evaluates to `101`.

`flags = prev_flags & ~( state & stateMask )` evaluates to `101 &= 100`, i.e. `100`

`flags | ( state & stateMask )` evaluates to `100 | 010`, i.e. `110`.